# Secret key expiration

Tags: keys, blind-signature

I am looking for suitable techniques through which secret keys (RSA/ ElGamal / ring signatures secret keys) can be expired after a certain time limit. So far, I found out that only PGP offers expiration.

Answer (score 5):

Private keys do not have an expiration date. They are expired by destroying them.

Certificates have expiration dates, and the public key inside certificates - and therefore the certificate itself - relates 1:1 with the private key. A PGP "public key" contains a lot of meta-information and is more like a certificate than a public key, despite their name. Certificates have an expiration date, after which the certificate / public key is generally not used to verify the signature anymore.

Expiration is generally not part of the cryptographic algorithms; it's more of a responsibility of the system / implementation than cryptography itself.

---

Note that I always call asymmetric key pairs as *private* / public key pairs as the private keys are not shared. Symmetric keys just need to remain secret between the parties that use them. Secret keys *may* be private as well, if they are not shared at all. Some books confuse the notion of private vs secret, possibly because both public and private keys both have "pk" as acronym.